# Regex to extract LHS and RHS of a char

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a Regex for the below problem -

String - `"32 - This-may-contain - hypen-as-well"`

Divide from `"-"`

Result -> `"32 "`, `" This-may-contain - hypen-as-well"`

I was doing `"32 - This-may-contain-hypen-as-well".split("-");` but the RHS can also contain hypens and I need to do more operations to join back the rhs with hypen.

Comment: What about `.split(' - ')`? (I added spaces either side of the hyphen)

Comment: @evolutionxbox RHS can contain " - " as well

Comment: that's OK ... coz you can re-join on the same string to get the RHS

Comment: or you can get the indexOf `-`

Comment: @JaromandaX I am looking for a regex for it

Answer (score 0):

use the regex as below in a match

```js
const input = "32 - This-may-contain - hypen-as-well";
const result =input.match(/(.*?) - (.*)/).slice(1);
console.log(result);
```

but without regex it still can be done

```js
const input = "32 - This-may-contain - hypen-as-well";
const [LHS, ...RHS] = input.split(' - ');
const result = [LHS, RHS.join(' - ')];
console.log(result);
```